# Discord.js - get reactions count from a specific message after a timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made the bot send a message from a channel `A` to channel `B` with two reactions (1️⃣ and 2️⃣)
I now need to calculate the count of each reaction after a timeout reaches the end, everything is setup except getting the counts.
I found documentations about using Partials but couldn't figure out how to implement that here or is it a good choice to do so, ***the question here is how to get the reactions count for each of the mentioned reactions?***

here my code:

```
var optionYesCount = 0;
var optionNoCount = 0;
//sending a notification message in channel A then sending the vote message in channel B
message.channel.send("Hello! voting is open in channel `B`").then(
    //sending a welcome message in channel B
    client.channels.cache.get('channel_B_id').send("voting ends 2 minutes")
    .then(
      //starting the vote
      setTimeout(() => {
        client.channels.cache.get('channel_B_id').send({
          embed: {
            color: 8359053,
            title: `VOTING OPEN`,
            description: "1️⃣: yes and 2️⃣: no"
          }
      }).then(m => m.react('1️⃣')).then(m => m.message.react("2️⃣"));
      //ending the vote and displaying results
      setTimeout(() => {
        client.channels.cache.get('channel_B_id').send({
          embed: {
            color: 8359053,
            title: "VOTING ENDED WITH RESULTS",
            description: `Option 1️⃣: ${optionYesCount}\nOption 2️⃣: ${optionNoCount}`,
          }
        });
      }, 10000)
    }, 10000)
  )
);
```

I should mention that the code is nested within this if statement:

```
//PREFIX is '='
if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
    const [ISSUED_CMD, ...args] = message.content.trim().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    if(ISSUED_CMD === 'vote'){
        //voting code above
    }
}
```

Comment: look at `message.awaitReactions` didn't cover that case?

Comment: @Sarabadu I don't think I can use that here, but that led me to a new method `.createReactionCollector()` which looks like it is the solution that only thing I couldn't get is how to reference the desired message ? it goes like this `message.createReactionCollector(filterRedSide, { time: 9000 });`

Comment: ohh ok i've take it from here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions

Comment: @Sarabadu there I sent a message across channels if I use just "message.[...]" I will be collecting reactions from the wrong message! the message sent with the embed title "VOTING OPEN" is the message where I should be collecting reactions! (I hope you get my point)

Comment: i was thinking on this  `....}).then(m => m.react('1️⃣')).then(m => m.message.react("2️⃣")).then(m => m.awaitReactions(filter....) );`  but maybe i missing something

Comment: @Sarabadu that could work, let me work on it a bit

Comment: @Sarabadu I tried `.then(m => m.awaitReactions)` and it returned an error saying that "m.awaitReactions() is not a function" and then I tried `.then(m => m.message.awaitReactions())`and it says 'Cannot read property 'awaitReactions' of undefined'